# Geometric intersection number

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question, surfaces, geometric-topology

This question might be vague, or possibly might not have any answer. I am looking for an alternative definition of geometric intersection number. Recall that we have the following standard definition:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a orientable surface without boundary and
> $\alpha,\beta:\Bbb S^1\to \Sigma$ be two closed curves. Define
> $$|\alpha\cap \beta|:=\begin{cases}\#\big\{(z,w)\in \Bbb S^1\times\Bbb
>  S^1:\alpha(z)=\beta(w)\big\} &\text{ if }\alpha\not=\beta,\\ 
>  \frac{1}{2}\#\big\{(z,w)\in \Bbb S^1\times\Bbb S^1:z\not= w\text{ and 
>  }\alpha(z)=\alpha(w)\big\}&\text{ if }\alpha=\beta.\end{cases}$$ Now,
> the geometric intersection number is defined  as
> $$i\big([\alpha],[\beta]\big):=\min_{\alpha\sim
> \alpha',\beta\sim\beta'}|\alpha'\cap \beta'|.$$ Here, $\sim$ denotes
> free homotopy, and $[\ ]$ denotes the free homotopy class.

Recently I got another definition, might be equivalent to the standard one, using liftings $\widetilde \alpha,\widetilde \beta$ of the curves $\alpha,\beta$ in the cover corresponding to the subgroups $\langle[\alpha]\rangle,\langle[\beta]\rangle$  of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ and then considering the full pre-image of $\text{image}(\widetilde \alpha)$ in the universal cover, and then projecting this full pre-image in cover corresponding to $\langle[\beta]\rangle$, and then counting the number of intersection points.

> Can anyone suggest to me a reference to this new definition? Any other
> alternative definition is also welcome.

Comment: Can you leave a reference for the second definition? I don’t think I understand it